# angularjs closure compiler ngRoute: Unknow Provider when minified

Tags: angularjs, minify, google-closure-compiler

Yet another post about angularjs, minify and ngRoute...

However, I really have no idea why the minified code is failing while the normal version isn't:

I've isolated the issue to this file (appRoutes.js) containing the appRoutes module.

Not Minified:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute'])

.config(

    ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$logProvider',

    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $logProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {   ... });
        $httpProvider.response... );
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    }])
.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http){ ... })]);
```

Minified

```
angular.module("appRoutes",["ngRoute"])
.config(
    ["$routeProvider","$locationProvider","$httpProvider","$logProvider",

    function(a,d,e,f){
        a.when("/",{

        etc...
```

And I'm being given this error:

```
Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- $http
```

Sorry, but I can't figure what the h*ll's wrong with that... ?

The only systematic issue is that the minified version "a" of $routeProvider is the source of the issue... it's just sometimes called b or c...

It works NOT minified, but doesn't work minified...

I tried without the inline annotation.
I tried to use Gulp Closure Compiler and the compiler.jar directly by command line.
I tried to change the order in which the modules are called.
I've got a file called app.js; it's the main angularjs file that calls all dependencies, and appRoutes is in it...

Thaks for your help!

Comment: How have you isolated it to that point in your code? `a` will be throughout your minified code, so my guess is you have forgotten `[]` somewhere else.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply.
It turned out you were right, it just took a night sleep to identify the source of the problem.
It was my $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function($q, $location) { that didn't have inline annotation... obviously...